# How to Download S3 Object and store it on server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to Download Private S3 Object and store it on website Server

Here is what I'm Trying

```
    $s3 = new S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => 'ap-south-1',
        'credentials' => array(
            'key' => '*****',
            'secret' => '*******'
        )
    ]);

 $command = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', array(
   'Bucket' => 'bucket_name',
   'Key'    => 'object_name_in_s3'  
   'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.$my_file_name.'"'
));

$signedUrl = $command->createPresignedUrl('+15 minutes');
echo $signedUrl;
```

How can i save these files on my server

Answer (score 2):

From [Get an Object Using the AWS SDK for PHP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html):

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';
$filepath = '*** Your File Path ***';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Save object to a file.
$result = $s3->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $keyname,
    'SaveAs' => $filepath
));
```

If you just want to download a file from the command line (instead of an app), you can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) -- it has an `aws s3 cp` command.

The [Pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html) in your code can be used to grant time-limited access to a private object stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. Typically, your application generates the URL and includes it in a web page for users to click and download the object. There is no need to use it on the server-side, because the server would have credentials that are authorized to access content in Amazon S3.

Comment: I tried your code but my object is private and aws sdk is resulting in simple link of the file like this `https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/examle/files/U_zk2nMHTNVgJu1ZYQPoCdAicbjv6yl7Gw9Fr3fhKeDLtxpWSRaO4m0s.zip`  It is not generating presigned url

Comment: That is correct. Why do you want a pre-signed URL? You said "I'm trying to Download Private S3 Object and store it on website Server" -- that doesn't need a pre-signed URL. It needs normal AWS credentials. If you're downloading on an EC2 instance, then assign a Role to the instance and it will automatically get credentials. If that isn't what you're doing, please Edit your question and add more details (eg where is the webserver).